# Show number of users currently editing

Tags: discussion, feature-request, edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Lock a post for editing, or at least display a warning](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141252/lock-a-post-for-editing-or-at-least-display-a-warning)

Very often two or three people will start editing the same poorly formatted question, only for most of them to get the `This post has been edited x times` message before they can submit their edit.

I think it is a waste of energy for several people to work on the same task when they could be editing another post. Additionally, this puts pressure on you to rush your edit, making it easier for you to miss minor flaws. This means the post ends up with 5 or 6 incremental edits, instead of one solid edit that addresses most issues.

My suggestion is that we could have a numeric indication of how many people are currently editing a post next to the `edit` link, so that you don't waste your time if someone has it covered.

Comment: In my opinion, better [lock the post from editing](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141252/lock-a-post-for-editing-or-at-least-display-a-warning?rq=1) upon the first user who starts editing. Can't see real value in showing the number, will it really make a difference if it's one other, two others or 3 other users?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Yeah that works too. Didn't see it in the suggested questions. Voting to close.

Comment: I wouldn't actually support a lock so much as a warning, which is what I'm going for here.

Comment: Never meant this as duplicate, sorry.. anyway my point is that just showing "this post is being edited by other user" is enough and I think it already show such thing, just without the number.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd `I think it already show such thing` I didn't even know we already have this feature; where can I see if a post is being edited?