# Why there is no Syncing Mechanism for Editing posts?

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

It happened many times that I submit an `Edit Suggestion` and immediately after that I see the post has already been edited by another guy *(usually higher-rep)* and my edit has been rejected by either Community or reviewers.

Why there is no mechanism to prevent simultaneous edits and avoid *unfair* rejection?

This is my first attempt to edit the post:
[image]

As you can see it got rejected by community because another user submitted an edit. And immediately after that I wanted to re-edit my edit which turned to this (*Actually it rolled back all the edits*):

[image]

Comment: +1 ,same thing happened with me too many times.

Comment: It's totally annoying and makes me ignore crappy posts.

Comment: Edits are indeed automatically rejected when someone with the direct edit privilege was *also* editing. If your edits were rejected by reviewers, your edit was *not good enough*.

Comment: It seems your feature request is similar to this earlier one? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141252/lock-a-post-for-editing-or-at-least-display-a-warning

Comment: Conversely, I have the direct edit privilege and my edits have been rejected when a rather crap suggested edit has been approved and my own, which fixes the *entire* post, is deemed insubstantial. ;)

Comment: @MartijnPieters, NO. My edit was similar to the one that got accepted (even better). But it got disappear when I submit it.

Comment: @Bart, Thanks for pointing out. That's the fully-researched version of my question.

Comment: @SamRad: Sorry, but [this edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1723864) does not look correct to me.

Comment: @MartijnPieters That might be a  system glitch. See this suggested edit: http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1723861

Comment: @MartijnPieters, that's exactly the reason that I posted this question. I will edit my question.

Comment: Mostly when we suggest edits on newbie's (in SE) posts, they just ignore it and edit the post themselves. And our [good suggestions](http://dba.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/8886) get rejected by Community ♦.

Comment: @hims056, I'm aware of that but that wasn't my case. The original poster did not edit his post.

Answer (score 0):

Because that higher privileged user is... well... higher privileged.

His edit privileged will not be locked out just because any (potentially anonymous) user is *suggesting* an edit to the post.

Also, we don't know which edit is better, nor we know whether he started editing, and didn't finish or left the tab open.

The idea is good, but you can't cleanly implement it without introducing a whole set of problems.

Comment: Paradox. You first assume the Higher-Reps have priority and then you say you don't know which edit is better.

Comment: Obviously the system decides *somehow* which edit is better. See my comment above about crap suggested edits sometimes overruling by-far more substantial direct edits. =)