# Show when edits are pending to avoid "why can't I edit this"

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, edits

I understand when edits are pending the "edit" button is grayed out. See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/84676/193412) for other situations.

My suggestion is to make it more obvious if there is a pending edit - consider the two questions below, there is no indication as to why I cannot edit the first as the only difference is "edit" being grayed out.

Adding

```
(Edit Pending)
```

just to the right of "Flag" would be a good way to make this considerably more clear.

---

> [image][image]

Comment: I think hovering over the greyed out edit button would give you the info already.

Comment: @Mat I think people with an edit ban see a similarly greyed out button. I've seen meta posts were people have thought they were edit banned because of this

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141252/lock-a-post-for-editing-or-at-least-display-a-warning

Comment: Also doesn't it show `edit (1)` if there is a suggested edit still being reviewed?

Comment: @AaronBertrand Only if you have the ability to review it.

Comment: @animuson ah, gotcha

Answer (score 3):

A fix for this is live.

Instead of greying out the edit button, the button will appear as normal and clicking it will bring up an error message with the same text that used to appear on hover:

[image: Screenshot of error message when trying to edit a post with an existing suggested edit.]

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. :D

Comment: I must say I liked the old situation better. The hover worked fine and it was nice to see (**without having to click**) that you can't edit at the moment.

Comment: Possibly worth noting that this also changed how attempts to edit on meta with low rep work? "Suggested edits are not allowed on non-tag-wiki posts on meta sites." I don't know if this is documented anywhere, though.

Comment: Please fix [this bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/298797/349538). It's been reported several times but still hasn't been fixed.