# Editing a post during review doesn't show an "edit not possible" message

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, edits, suggested-edits

While reviewing First Posts on Super User, I noticed that I couldn't edit this question (see below). Clicking the "edit" link simply does nothing.

Editing is not possible for me right now because I have already five suggested edits pending. It used to be the case that the link would've been grayed out (and the reason shown as a popover). [This has been changed recently](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/198440/295232), and while I'm not sure it's an improvement, the current implementation needs some fixing at least.

[image]

This bug appears regardless of the actual reason that the edit isn't possible; for instance, [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/299644/295232) is another user experiencing the same bug who couldn't suggest an edit because of an already pending one.

Apparently, I'm far from the only one who experiences this issue. As of last Sunday morning, [15 other bug reports](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/812101/2-many-bug-reports) have been posted networkwide (and are still alive) and [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/363952/4751173) is #16.

Comment: It's an improvement if you're the one that has to deal with people writing in asking why they can't edit because they don't know there's a tooltip. ;) But I'm not sure why that wouldn't work out of the box in review. That's weird.

Comment: @animuson can we have a compromise: the edit link can be clicked *but* it is grayed out?

Comment: This just happened to me. It's really annoying. I hope they will fix it soon.

Comment: @DonaldDuck yeah, me too. On MSO and MSE combined, this bug has now been reported more than 10 times ...

Comment: Also a duplicate on Meta Arqade... https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12770/review-queue-edit-link-does-not-display-warning-messages

Comment: Strangely, this happened for me even when I could do an edit from the question link without any message like 'edit not possible;

Comment: Has there been any progress with this issue? It's been almost 9 months, and makes reviewing rather frustrating.

Comment: Also reported on Physics: https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10952/44126

Comment: Reported about ELU:https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/321743/faulty-edit-button?noredirect=1#comment1053174_321743

Comment: Just to find it more quickly, here’s this issue reported on Meta.SO: [No error message is shown in the review queue when suggesting an edit is not possible](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/356056/4642212).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is [now fixed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/380969/2157772):

> Starting with the next build, we'll be showing an error message same way as we do on regular question pages:
>
> [image: Error message on clicking "edit" in review]