# "Edit waiting" warning did not appear in First Posts Queue

Tags: bug, review, edits, warning

I was reviewing a post in the **First Posts Queue** when I came across a question I wanted to answer, for reference the question I am talking about is linked this one:

[after reading bytes from a file in binary mode, how to find the current position](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45641130/8150685)

I noticed some easy edits that would make it look nice however when I clicked the **edit** button nothing happened (as if the *edit* link was dead).  I opened the question in a normal link and the warning regarding an edit is curently waiting popped up:

[image]

I would imagine that in the **a review queue** if someone tries to edit a question (as they would in a normal question) this warning should also pop up but it did not for me.

Is this a bug?

Comment: I marked this as a duplicate but it is technically different than the other one.  The other one is because he hit his max pending edits where as mine was because a edit was pending on the post (i.e. it wasn't my pending post).  Should I edit that question?

Comment: The title on that (my) question is already generic and covers your case. I'm quite sure that when they solve 'my' bug, they solve yours as well, but I'll add a footnote.