# Faulty edit button?

Tags: support, edits, action-buttons

I was in the middle of a 'First posts' review queue when I came across an answer in need of formatting.  I clicked the 'edit' button and nothing happened, except the link in the top bar changing briefly, but then it flashed back and nothing happened.  A few hours later, I had an edit approved, then it started working again.  What was going on?

Comment: Any chance you already had 5 edits pending, or there already was a suggested edit pending on that particular post?

Comment: @Tinkeringbell Not sure, and no.

Comment: You do have [5 pending edits](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/327571/lordology?tab=activity&sort=suggestions) so that is the max, and there is a known issue that this rate limit condition isn't properly handled during review.

Comment: Is there a citable link to your last piece of information?

Comment: Related: *[Rate limit suggested edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210416)*