# Getting Duplicate Questions from Stack Exchange API

Tags: support, duplicate-questions, api

I want to use api.stackexchange.com to get duplicate questions.

**Scenario:**

- I get a question from api.stackexchange.com using `GET .../questions/{my_question_id}`.
- In the next step I would like to get a list of `ids` that refer to duplicate question of `my_question_id`.

---

Is there any API that allows this?

Comment: Can you try the [linked questions api](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/linked-questions), in the result set, which are having the `"closed_reason": "duplicate"` are the duplicate questions to the given question id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible with the [linked questions API call](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/linked-questions), but you'll need to do some work to filter out the real duplicates (as opposed to question which are merely linked by mentioning the original question in posts or comments).

The default [filter](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/filters) includes a `closed_reason` which will have the value `duplicate`, but it could be that it's closed as duplicate of *another* question. Therefore, you need to add the `closed_details` to the filter:

[image]

and check the `original_questions` element. For example, to find the many duplicates of [Editing a post during review doesn't show an "edit not possible" message](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/298797/295232) you can call the following URL: https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/298797/linked?order=desc&sort=activity&site=meta&filter=!9Z(-wvHE( and look for its `question_id`, 298797.

[image]