# Editing a post during review doesn't show an "edit not possible" message (again)

Tags: bug, review, suggested-edits, error-message

I have encountered this problem before: [Editing a post during review doesn't show an "edit not possible" message](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/298797/295232), but it was fixed later on I guess the [Review queue workflows - Final release](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/369013/295232) broke this again. It doesn't matter if I click the 'edit' link in the post menu beneath the post (also visible on the Q&A page) or the 'Edit' option in the review sidebar widget; it doesn't inform me that I reached the maximum number of suggested edits on a site, like the regular pages do; only when I try to submit a suggested edit, an error occurs.

Comment: Is this different from [this issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/370543/348196)? I know the two messages communicate different things but I wonder if they both share the same root cause.