# Edit button doesn't show error in the review queue

Tags: bug, review, edits

I was reviewing first posts and noticed that I could not edit one of the posts (I had too many pending edits), normally there is an error message to explain this, however there isn't in the review queue (this is reproducible by me?):

[image]

I realise this is similar to [Why is the edit button disabled?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81681/why-is-the-edit-button-disabled) and [Show when edits are pending to avoid "why can't I edit this"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/198440/show-when-edits-are-pending-to-avoid-why-cant-i-edit-this) however I do know why it is disabled (I checked by trying to edit on a normal question) and the feature has `status-completed` (and is working outside of the review queues)

Is this a bug or intentional behaviour?

Comment: So, that red banner you're showing is the error you're getting *outside* the review queue?

Comment: @Catija yes - as I would expect

Comment: @animuson thanks, sorry don't know how I didn't find that! (actually maybe I was using site:stackoverflow.com as criteria).