# Mixed feedback for history links on tag wiki page if they're the default initial versions

Tags: feature-request, tag-wiki

When hovering over the 'history' or 'excerpt history' links on (meta) tag wikis like [this one](https://chess.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/discussion/info), their color changes (you can see the difference below, I was hovering over the 'history' link). This makes you think they're clickable, but they're not; at least, nothing happens.

[image]

Only if you hover for a longer time, the reason for this becomes clear: the popup will tell you

> This is the default initial version.

I'd like this message to be shown when you're clicking on the link as well (similar to how the [edit button works now if you can't suggest an edit to a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/298752/295232)), or alternatively make the links even lighter gray and not highlighting them while hovering.